# pdf reader that shows search results with correct page number

Tags: pdf, evince

If I search for a word in evince I get a list of search results on the left, with page numbers. These page numbers though are absolute page numbers of the pdf, not taking into account different page ranges for frontmatter (in roman numbers) and mainmatter. The following is from a minimum pdf of four pages, numbered i,ii,1,2, with a hit for my search on every page. Evince shows 1,2,3,4 instead. It can handle the page numbers correctly in the page field above. Is there another pdf viewer which does this correctly?

[image: evince screenshot]

Comment: Patch is here: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=756683 . To make it work with evince 3.10.3 in Ubuntu 14.04 one needs to slightly adapt it, but it works.